# laravel when query with array requests

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have colors request in array  `$colors = collect($request->colors);`

i am trying when query builder for make request when its not empty

```
$products = Product::when($colors, function ($query, $colors) {
   return $query->whereHas('colors', function (Builder $query) use ($colors) {
     $query->whereIn('slug',  $colors->toArray());
    });
 })
```

it should not be trigger color query

when i try

```
when(!$colors->isEmpty(), function ($query, $colors)
```

its trigger when there is array data in colors request
but inside query its return `boolean` instead of original array data

help!

Comment: The first parameter will always be the one to be evaluated as `true` or `false`, so if you do `!$colors->isEmpty()` that transforms automatically into a `boolean` and that is what `$colors` will be, so you have to use first code, not second. So, what is your problem with the first one ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti the problem with the first one is that an object is always `true`

Comment: One solution is as the user @lagbox shared (the best one), other solution but really not clean is do this: `$colors->isNotEmpty() ? $colors : false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use the `when` method there with that Collection you can scope in the `$colors` variable:

```
Product::when($colors->isNotEmpty(), function ($query) use ($colors) {
    ...
})...
```

Comment: `$colors->isNotEmpty() ? $colors : false` this fix my code